# finalizar una funcion en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, funciones

tengo un inconveniente con una función. En sí lo que hago es leer la bandeja de entrada de SMS y cuando ingresa un nuevo mensaje de texto éste se ejecuta. El problema viene a partir de la segunda vez que llamo a la misma función ya que no se actualiza sino que me lee el mismo mensaje y a partir de ahi se va atrasando un sms.

tengo dos archivos. el SmsReceiver que escucha la bandeja de entrada de sms.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static  SmsListener mListener;

Boolean b;
String abcd,xyz;



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
    Bundle data  = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus =  (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
    System.out.println("************************************************");
    System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL MESSENGERAddress DE SMS RECEIVER "+ pdus.length);
    for(int i= 0;i<pdus.length;i++){
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
         b=sender.endsWith("WNRCRP");

        String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
        String messageAddress = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();  // TRAE EL NUMERO DEL REMITENTE SMS
       // String messageBody = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
        System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL MESSENGERAddress DE SMS RECEIVER "+ messageAddress);
        System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL MESSENGERBOCY DE SMS RECEIVER "+ messageBody);

        mListener.messageReceived(messageAddress); //LE ENVIO A MessengeReceive QUE ESTA EN MAINACTIVITY EL NUMERO EL REMITENTE

    }
}
public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;

}

public interface SmsListener{
    public void messageReceived(String messageText);
}
```

}

y despues el MainActivity

en el onCreate llama a la función cuando recibe el llamado de un nuevo SMS

```
SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsReceiver.SmsListener() {

        @Override
        public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
            if (messageText.trim().equals(getString(R.string.numeroemisorGPS).trim())) { //COMPARO SI EL NUMERO DEL CUAL ME ENVIAN EL SMS ES IGUAL AL NUMERO DEL GPSESPERADO
                System.out.println("******* INGRESO A BUSCAR UBICACION ACTUALIZACION *******");
                //buscarUbicacionActualizacion(); //EN CASO DE QUE EL EMISOR SEA EL QUE ESPERO MANDO A LEER EL MENSAJE Y ACTUALIZAR EL MAPA

               buscarUbicacionNueva();


            }
        }
    });
```

y ésta es la función en sí.

```
 private void buscarUbicacionNueva() {   //SE USA AL COMENZAR LA APLICACION PARA VER CUAL FUE LA ULTIMA UBICACIÓN EN SMS
    Integer cantmensaje = 1;
    Integer mensajesErroneos  = 0;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(INBOX),null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.isFirst()) {

        while ( cantmensaje == 1) {
            //int inicio, fin = 0;
            System.out.println("CANTIDADD DE VUELTAS --> " + mensajesErroneos);
            int iniciolatitud, finlatitud, iniciolongitud, finlongitud, finlongitudS = 0;
            String longitud = "";
            String latitud = "";
            String cuerpo = "";

            cuerpo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")); //TOMA EL CUERPO DE LOS SMS
            String emisor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")); //TOMA EL NUMERO EMISOR DEL MENSAJE

            char[] caracteres = cuerpo.toCharArray();
            System.out.println("INGRESÒ A BUSCAR UBICACIÓN -->  ");
            System.out.println("posicion de SMS -->  " + emisor);

            System.out.println("ESTE ES EL MENSAJE  -->  "+cuerpo);
            if (emisor.equals(getString(R.string.numeroemisorGPS)) ) {    // consulto que el numero de emisor que quiero se encuentre en la bandeja de entrada y tomo la partes del mensaje que me interesan.
                iniciolatitud = cuerpo.indexOf("lat:") + 4;
                finlatitud = cuerpo.indexOf("long");
                iniciolongitud = cuerpo.indexOf("long") + 5;
                finlongitud = cuerpo.indexOf(",T:");
                finlongitudS = cuerpo.indexOf("speed");
                System.out.println("posicion de inicio LATITUD -->  " + iniciolatitud);
                System.out.println("Posicion final LATITUD --> " + finlatitud);
                System.out.println("posicion de inicio LONGITUD -->  " + iniciolongitud);
                System.out.println("Posicion final LONGITUD --> " + finlongitud);
                System.out.println("Posicion final LONGITUDS --> " + finlongitudS);
                Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae el CUERPO DEL MENSAJE   " + cuerpo);


                if (finlongitudS > finlongitud) {

                    latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitudS);
                } else if ((finlongitudS < finlongitud)) {
                    latitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpo.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitud);
                }

                if (iniciolatitud > 4) {
                    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    // webView.loadUrl(""+latitud);
                    webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud.trim() + "," + longitud.trim() + "&z=17");

                    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    //    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    //    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erroryaviene.html");
                    //          } });
                    Log.e("ya viene","http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud.trim() + "," + longitud.trim() + "&z=16");
                    //   Log.e("ya viene",""+latitud);
                    Log.e("PERMISOS","ingresa al mapa");
                    cantmensaje = cantmensaje + 1;
               return;
                }
                mensajesErroneos = mensajesErroneos +1;
                //System.out.println("CANTIDADD DE VUELTAS --> " + mensajesErroneos);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            else {//No hay SMS
                if (mensajesErroneos > 50) { //BUSCA ENTRE LOS ULTIMOS 50 SMS PARA VER SI HUBO UN PEDIDO DE GEOLOCALIZACIÓN
                    break;
                }
                Log.e("PERMISOS","no ingreso a view ");
                mensajesErroneos = mensajesErroneos +1;

                cursor.moveToNext();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes validar que se haya recibido el mensaje

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(String messageText) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                b=sender.endsWith("WNRCRP");

                String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                String messageAddress = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress(); // TRAE EL NUMERO DEL REMITENTE SMS
                // String messageBody = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL MESSENGERAddress DE SMS RECEIVER "+ messageAddress);
                System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL MESSENGERBOCY DE SMS RECEIVER "+ messageBody);

                mListener.messageReceived(messageAddress); //LE ENVIO A MessengeReceive QUE ESTA EN MAINACTIVITY EL NUMERO EL REMITENTE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si, eso también amigo, aunque de por si siempre se ejecuta cuando ingresa el sms. Pero el problema es otro. Es como si faltara un finish o algo asi que limpiara la caché de esa funcón (no se bien como explicar la falla tecnicamente) pero es como la caché de la pagina web que queda grabado la ultima ejecución